# Why can't I use LAZY fetching on inherited entities?

Tags: java, hibernate

Working with Hibernate 6.2.5.

I have a base entity class that uses `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance, e.g.:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "company)
@DiscriminatorColumn
public abstract class Business {
  // ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("corporation")
public class Corporation extends Business {
  // ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("llc")
public class LLC extends Business {
  // ...
}
```

My goal is to join to `Business` in another entity, fetching lazily:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "business_id", nullable = false)
  private Business business;

  // ...
}
```

This does not seem to work, as when I call `owner.getBusiness()`, it returns an instance of `Business$HibernateProxy`, not the subclass I expect. If I change the fetch type to `EAGER`, it works.

Is it possible to join fetching lazily on an inheritance entity?

Comment: Why do you say it does not seem to work? That is what happens when you lazy load entities. hibernate uses a proxy. If you are in a transaction, when you access any of the getters (except primary key getter e.g. `getId()` of the business proxy, hibernate will load the actual entity.

Comment: Because Hibernate does not resolve the subclass.